# Java sorting 2D array

Tags: java, computer-science

Given an 2d array like this

```
double[][] y = {{5,1},{0,0},{5,3},{5,2},{10,3},{12,100},{0,0}};
```

how would I sort it to where its like

```
{ {0,0},{0,0},{5,1},{5,2},{5,3},{10,3},{12,100} };
```

this is my current method

```
        Arrays.sort(sortedPoints, new Comparator<double[]>() {      
            @Override
            public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
                return Double.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you trying to sort it by its total sum? correct me if am wrong ?

Comment: Or you are trying to sort by elements at index 0 and then on index 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda will short :D

```
Arrays.sort(y, (d1, d2) -> Double.compare(d1[0] + d1[1], d2[0] + d2[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

this will only work if you are trying to sort based on sub-array sums,

```
Arrays.sort(sortedPoints, new Comparator<double[]>() {      
            @Override
            public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
                return Double.compare(o1[0]+o1[1],o2[0]+o2[1]);
            }
        });
```

made little changes to your code;

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array twice firstly by second field, and then by first.

So, here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Start");
    double[][] y = {{5,1},{0,0},{5,3},{5,2},{10,3},{12,100},{0,0}};

    Arrays.sort(y, (var a, var b) -> (int)(a[1]- b[1]));
    Arrays.sort(y, (var a, var b) -> (int)(a[0]- b[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("[" + y[i][0] + " , " + y[i][1] + "]");
    }

    System.out.println("End");}
}
```